# Zsh: How to force file completion everywhere following a set of characters?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I'm trying to figure out how to get file completion to work at any `word` position on the command line after a set of characters. As listed in a shell these characters would be `[     =+-\'\"()]` (the whitespace is tab and space). Zsh will do this, but only after the backtick character, '`', or `$(`. mksh does this except not after the characters `[+-]`.

By word position on the command line, I'm talking about each set of characters you type out which are delimited by space and a few other characters. For example,

`print Hello World`,

has three `words` at positions 1-3. At position 1, when you're first typing stuff in, completion is pretty much perfect. File completion works after all of the characters I mentioned. After the first `word`, the completion system gets more limited since it's smart. This is useful for commands, but limiting where you can do file completion isn't particularly helpful.

Here are some examples of where file completion doesn't work for me but should in my opinion:

`: ${a:=/...}`

`echo "${a:-/...}"`

`make LDFLAGS+='-nostdlib /.../crt1.o /.../crti.o ...'`

`env a=/... b=/... ...`

I've looked at rebinding `'^I'` (tab) with the handful of different completion widgets Zsh comes with and changing my `zstyle ':completion:*'` lines. Nothing has worked so far to change this default Zsh behaviour. I'm thinking I need to create a completion function that I can add to the end of my `zstyle ':completion:*' completer ...` line as a last resort completion.

In the completion function, one route would be to cut out the current `word` I want to complete, complete it, and then re-insert the completion back into the line if that's possible. It could also be more like `_precommand` which shifts the second `word` to the first `word` so that normal command completion works.

I was able to modify `_precommand` so that you can complete commands at any `word` position. This is the new file, I named it `_commando` and added its directory to my fpath:

```
#compdef -                                                              

# precommands is made local in _main_complete
precommands+=($words[1,$(( CURRENT -1 ))])

shift words
CURRENT=1

_normal
```

To use it I added it to the end of my `':completion:*' completer ...` line in my zshrc so it works with every program in `$path`. Basically whatever `word` you're typing in is considered the first `word`, so command completion works at every `word` position on the command line.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do the same thing for file completion, but it looks a little more complicated at first glace. I'm not really sure where to go with this, so I'm looking to get some help on this.

Answer (score 3):

I took a closer look at some of Zsh's builtin functions and noticed a few that have special completion behaviour. They belong to the `typeset` group, which has a function `_typeset` in the default `fpath`. I only needed to extract a few lines for what I wanted to do. These are the lines I extracted:

```
...
elif [[ "$PREFIX" = *\=* ]]; then
compstate[parameter]="${PREFIX%%\=*}"
compset -P 1 '*='
_value
...
```

These few lines allow typeset completion after each slash in a command like this:

```
typeset file1=/... file2=~/... file3=/...
```

I extrapolated from this to create the following function. You can modify it to put in your `fpath`. I just defined it in my zshrc like this:

```
_reallyforcefilecompletion() {
    local prefix_char

    for prefix_char in ' ' $'\t' '=' '+' '-' "'" '"' ')' ':'; do
        if [[ "$PREFIX" = *${prefix_char}* ]]; then
            if [[ "$PREFIX" = *[\'\"]* ]]; then
                compset -q -P "*${prefix_char}"
            else
                compset -P "*${prefix_char}"
            fi
            _value
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

You can use this by adding it to a `zstyle` line like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _reallyforcefilecompletion
```

This way, it's only used as a last resort so that smarter completions can try before it. Here's a little explanation of the function starting with the few variables and the command involved:

`prefix_char`: This gets set to each prefix character we want to complete after. For example, `env a=123` has the prefix character `=`.

`PREFIX`: Initially this will be set to the part of the current word from the beginning of the word up to the position of the cursor; it may be altered to give a common prefix for all matches.

`IPREFIX` (not shown in code): `compset` moves string matches from `PREFIX` to `IPREFIX` so that the rest of `PREFIX` can be completed.

`compset`: This command simplifies modification of the special parameters, while its return status allows tests on them to be carried out.

`_value`: Not really sure about this one. The documentation states it plays some sort of role in completion.

[Documentation for the completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html)

**The function:** In the second line, we declare `prefix_char` `local` to avoid variable pollution. In line three, we start a `for` loop selecting each `prefix_char` we want to complete after. In the next `if` block, we check if the variable `PREFIX` ends with one of the `prefix_chars` we want to complete after and if `PREFIX` contains any quotes. Since `PREFIX` contains quotes, we use `compset -q` to basically allow quotes to be ignored so we can complete in them. `compset -P` strips `PREFIX` and moves it to `IPREFIX`, basically so it gets ignored and completion can work.

The next `elif` statement is for a `PREFIX` ending with prefix_char but not containing quotes, so we only use `compset -P`. I added the `return 0` to break the loop. A more correct way to make this function would be in a `case` statement, but we're not using the `compset` return value, so this works. You don't see anything about file completion besides `_value`. For the most part we just told the system to ignore part of the `word`.

---

Basically this is what the function does. We have a line that looks like:

```
env TERM=linux PATH=/<---cursor here
```

The cursor is at the end of that slash. This function allows PREFIX, which is PATH=, to be ignored, so we have:

```
env TERM=linux /<---cursor here
```

You can complete a file there with `PATH=` removed. The function doesn't actually remove the `PATH=` though, it just recategorizes it as something to ignore.

With this function, you can now complete in all of the examples I listed in the question and a lot more.

One last thing to mention, adding this `force-list` line in your zshrc cripples this function somehow. It still works but seems to choke. This new force-list function is way better anyway.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' force-list always
```

EDIT: There were a couple lines I forgot to copy into the function. Probably should have checked before posting. I think it's good now.

Comment: Thanks for your work! It doesn't work for me, though. Could you describe where to put the code (Can both the function and the `zstyle` command be in `.zshrc`)? Also, it would be interesting to know what you mean with "choke".